# Get two short subtitles out of a too long title

Tags: strings

Is there a way to get n shorter strings out of a long one in Latex? Let's say I have something like `\title{A very long title}` and I want it to be broken into two pieces such that I can later use `colorbox{red}{A very}` and `\color{blue}{long title}`. The break point should be calculated through a distance provided by the user.

Comment: Out of `\title`, yes, but you'll have to store the content first/before `\maketitle` since most document classes remove `\@title` - the placeholder macro. By distance, you mean characters?

Comment: @Werner by distance, I mean "if it is longer than 8cm break the title". Here the use of the `\title{}` command was just an example. What I have in mind is related to the `\chapter{}` command.

Comment: I don't think that, even if feasible in general, such an automatic procedure is good: breaking a title requires semantic considerations. For instance `The story of\\my life` would probably be better split as `The story\\of my life`.

Comment: ok, so the user could indicated where the title should be broken but the two (sub-)strings are still desired.

Comment: in which case a new command `\chapter[optional]{substring1}{substring2}` should be designed?

Comment: `\chapter[The real long title]{\textcolor{red}{The real}\\\textcolor{green}{long title}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need anything special for the `\chapter` command:

```
\chapter[The real long title]
  {\textcolor{red}{The real}\\
   \textcolor{green}{long title}}
```

is all you need. You can abstract it with new commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\firstchapline}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\secondchapline}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\coloredchapter}{som}
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\chapter*{#3}}
   {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\make@coloredchapter{#3}}
     {\chapter[#2]{#3}}%
   }%
 }
 \newcommand{\make@coloredchapter}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \let\firstchapline\@firstofone
   \let\secondchapline\@firstofone
   \let\\\space
   \protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\chapter[#1]}%
   \x{#1}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\coloredchapter{\firstchapline{A really}\\\secondchapline{long title}}
\coloredchapter[Short title]{\firstchapline{A really}\\\secondchapline{long title}}
\coloredchapter*{\firstchapline{A really}\\\secondchapline{long title}}
\end{document}
```

[image]